How do I generate static dates for the null rows that come in as closed?



ID
Status
datecol




1
closed
2024-04-18


2
closed
2024-04-12


3
closed
NULL


4
closed
NULL



Let say Id 3 came in as closed on 2024/4/19 with datecol null, How can i populate it with the date it came in as closed(in this case: 2024/04/19). And what if id 4 was to come in five (5) days after Id 3 with datecol null, How would I populate it with 2024/04/24.
Here is what I tried:
Case when status = "closed" and datecol is null then getdate() else datecol end as dateecol.

welcome to SO. what do you mean by "populate"? do you want to update data in a table or just query it? can you show your query?

Does this answer your question? Default Value for DATETIME column in SQL Server Management Studio 2017

@BenderBoy  let's say 10 rows came in today with a closed status but the date col  was null, I want to be able replace the null if today's date and have it stay that way moving forward. if another five rows come in tomorrow with closed status but datecol is null then I want to replace their nulls with the date they came in as nulls.

@dropoutcoder Do I include my cast statement in alter statement?

Let's say you look at this table in 20240425, how do you know when the rows "came in". the only chance you get is to assign the value when you insert them, either by using a DEFAULT or explicit CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE).

What happen with just a simple CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN ISNULL(datecol, GETDATE()) ELSE datecol END?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
